# Waiting for UI Thread to finish operation in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, ui-thread

I am in this situation in my `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    new Thread(() -> {

        Object obj;

        while (true) {

            // update obj

            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                // display obj
            });

        }

    }).start();

}
```

The problem here is that the update operation is not synchronized with the display operation: I always end up skipping a value because `obj` is updated before the UI thread is able to show its old value.

What is the correct way to wait for the UI Thread to finish its job of displaying `obj` and only then proceed to the next iteration?

Comment: I don't think you've actually explained your issue well, but in general you don't synchronize with the UI thread this way.  Both threads do their thing asynchronously, and that's important.  If you really think you need to synchronize, I think you'll need to explain better what you're actually trying to do.  I think there's an XY problem here/

Comment: Link to XY Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: In the end I solved it by running both operations on the UI thread

Comment: That's almost certainly the wrong solution. Instead, you should normally use a _callback_ that gets executed when the worker thread is finished.

Comment: @outsidethecave Running your both operations on the UI thread may freeze and crash the app if the operations took too long to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *callback* here

Like,

```
//Extending the Activity is left here since it isn't the subject
public class MyClass implements MyThread.CallbackListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
      
        new MyThread(this).start(); 

        //Your codes that do not require synchronization with the above thread
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onObjectUpdated(Object obj){
        //Your code that needs to be synchronized. In your case display your object here
    }
}
```

And your *MyThread* class will be

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    Object obj;
    CallbackListener listener; 
   
    public MyThread(CallbackListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }  
    
    public void run(){
       while (true) {
          // update obj
          listener.onObjectUpdated(obj);
       }
    }

    public interface CallbackListener{
       void onObjectUpdated(Object obj);
    } 
}
```

What we are doing here is just making a method call when the object has updated.

When the object has updated, your *onObjectUpdated* method in *MyClass* will be called so that making your code synchronized. And you can put any non-synchronized code in the *onCreate* method itself.